# Block sites from setting any data using selenium Java (chrome)

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, cookies

I'm trying to launch browser with disabled cookies, I found a way for blocking third-party but haven't found a way to block sites from setting any data (block cookies) on chrome browser.

```
 ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    Map prefs = new HashMap();
    prefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.cookies", 2);
    options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: What is your exact testing steps? Can you show us some of your work please?

Comment: I'm just trying to launch chrome driver with disabled cookies, I have added the code.

Comment: Does using `profile.default_content_settings.cookies` works for you? What is the error/issue you are facing?

Comment: No it doesn't work, i'm not getting any issue but instead I'm looking into advance settings -> cookies and the cookies aren't blocked.

Comment: Is it that you found a way to blocking third-party cookies?

Comment: Now you just want an option to "block sites from setting any data" ? I think if you have done the first part successfully the second one is also done.

Comment: Else let me know, I have a solution for you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.cookies", 2);
```